# C# - Create setInterval / clearInterval functions

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and try to create a `setInterval` and `clearInterval` function which is exactly working like the same functions in javascript.

I do it mainly for practice and to learn what can be done in C# and what not.

**setInterval**

---

**Requirements:** Create a new timer and return it, also run a anonymous function or a predefined function again and again in the given interval.

```
    Timer setInterval(Func<int> myMethod, int intervalInMs)
    {
        var timer = new Timer();
        timer.Start();

        while (true) {   //probably a infinite loop
            if (timer.ElapsedMilliseconds >= intervalInMs)
            {

                myMethod();
                timer.Restart();
            }
        }

        return timer;  //Code does never reach this part obviously because of the while loop
    }
```

**clearInterval**

---

**Requirements:** Stop the timer.

```
    void clearInterval(Timer timer)
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }
```

---

**Planned Usage**

```
    Timer myTimer = setInterval(delegate {
        MessageBox.Show(
            "test",
            "test",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Warning
        );

        return 1;
    }, 5000);


    //somewhere in code...

    clearInterval(myTimer);
```

How is it possible to solve this with C#, by using Events?

Comment: Solve what? Your question is not clear.

Comment: `while (true) { //probably a infinite loop` no probably in it, this **is** an infinite loop

Comment: Yes this is obviously just a concept, not working code. Thats why I ask how to solve these problems and how to create the javascript equivalents of `setInterval` and `clearInterval`

Comment: why are you returning a result form this method? It never returns anything as your looping permanently. BTW this will cause a stackoverflow...

Comment: @Liam, as I said. This is just a concept and I ask how to solve these problems.

Comment: Solve these problems isn't a question.

Comment: Instead of trying to write your own timer implementation, have you considered to use an existing timer implementation, for example like the [`System.Threading.Timer` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @bassfader, No, my goal is to code the exact equivalent of `setInterval` and `clearInterval` from javascript for learning purposes.

Comment: @Black If this is about learning, then I'd suggest to look into the source code of existing implementations to learn from them, instead of trying to create your own from scratch. But be aware that a real timer implementation may not be as simple as it sounds like (you'll need at least a basic understanding of threading in C# to really understand the code). You can for example take a look at the source code of the `System.Threading.Timer` implementation using the following link: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs

Comment: @bassfader My goal was not to create my own timer, but to create a function which works similar as the `setInterval` method from javascript. I already solved it and added it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .Net framework provides at least three different timers - [`System.Timers.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).
The [`System.Diagnostic.Stopwatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) is not a timer and should not be used as one. It only measures how much time have passed between the `Start()` and `Stop()`.

I would suggest using one of the timers provided by the .Net framework instead of re-inventing the wheel.

### update

Well, since you insisted, 
Here is a simple implementation **NOT FOR USE IN PRODUCTION CODE** since it's very easy to create memory leaks with it:

```
public static class Interval
{
    public static System.Timers.Timer Set(System.Action action, int interval)
    {
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval);
        timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => {
            timer.Enabled = false;
            action();
            timer.Enabled = true;
        };
        timer.Enabled = true;
        return timer;
    }

    public static void Stop(System.Timers.Timer timer)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/OSQJ6830)

Comment: I want to code the javascript equivalents for `setInterval` and `clearInterval` for learning purposes, of course my code has many errors, it is only a concept.

Comment: 1. As far as I remember, `SetInterval` is not a part of javascript, it's a part of the Document Object Model. 2. c# is very far from javascript is many ways. attempting to create "equivalents" is bound to fail.

Comment: setInterval is a javascript method. So you say it is impossible to create a setInterval method in C# ?

Comment: I don't say it's impossible, I say it's not going to be **exactly** the same. Also, I say that it's pointless, since the framework already gives you built in timers. Oh, and SetInterval is a part of the browser dom - it's a member of the Window object. but that's just nitpicking.

Comment: learning is never pointless. And in my oppinion it would make working much easier if I would have a function like `setInterval`

Comment: Pointless things? I just solved it and I learned alot during the process, so how is it pointless If I have more knowledge now than before?

Comment: be careful of memory leaks.

Comment: How can I create a memory leak in this case?

Comment: Not stopping the interval will create a memory leak.

Comment: Im not sure why, garbage collection should prevent it. What is the reason for the leak, just curious? You are basically just starting a timer and run code, just like you would do without the interval class, so what is the difference?

Comment: I am running a memory performance test with 10 separate intervals doing some mathematic operations every 100ms-200ms with my interval class right now. I will let it run for 10 hours and see if it does really leak memory.

Comment: The Timer class implements the IDisposable interface. Classes that implements the IDisposable interface needs to be properly disposed, since they usually use unmanaged resources that the garbage collector can't release. That's why they have the Dispose method. Using a class like that and simply set it's reference to null will usually cause a memory leak. If you are doing it multiple times, you might even end up with a memory leak that will effect performance.

Comment: So you can prevent a memory leak by calling the dispose method if you clear the interval or if you never stop an interval?
PS: I updated my answer with a screenshot of a 260 minutes memory usage test run.

Comment: You can prevent memory leaks by using IDisposable classes the way they should be used - and dispose them when done, either explicitly or implicitly with the using statement.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve it by using events. It is maybe not the best solution, but as I already mentioned, I am a C# beginner.

**Example:**

This example shows a message box every 5000 ms, after three Messageboxes the interval is changed and at 10 boxes the interval is cleared. You can also stop the interval by pressing the button.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Intervals
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Interval ival1 = new Interval();
        private int _A;

        public int A
        {
            get { return _A; }
            set {
                _A = value;

                if (value == 3) {
                    if (ival1 != null) {
                        MessageBox.Show(
                            "changeInterval Triggered",
                            A.ToString(),
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Warning
                        );
                        ival1.changeInterval(1000);
                    }
                }

                if (value >= 10)
                {
                    if (ival1 != null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(
                            "clearInterval Triggered",
                            A.ToString(),
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Warning
                        );
                        ival1.clearInterval();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            int interval = 5000;

            ival1.setInterval(delegate {
                A++;

                MessageBox.Show(
                    A.ToString(),
                    "A",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Warning
                );
            }, interval);
        }

        private void stopInterval_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ival1.clearInterval();
        }
    }
}
```

---

I created a new class `Interval` which is needed in order for this program to work.

---

```
using System;

namespace Intervals
{
    public class Interval
    {
        private System.Timers.Timer timer;
        private Action main;

        public Interval()
        {
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        }

        public void setInterval(Action pAction, int interval)
        {
            if (interval <= 0) { interval = 100; }
            timer.Interval = interval;

            main = new Action(delegate{
                timer.Stop();
                pAction?.Invoke();
                timer.Start();
            });

            timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => TimerEventProcessor(sender, e);
            timer.Start();
        }

        public void changeInterval(int interval)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            timer.Interval = interval;
            timer.Start();
        }

        public void clearInterval()
        {
            main?.EndInvoke(null);

            main = delegate
            {
                timer.Stop();
                timer.Dispose();
            };
        }

        public void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
        {
            main?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

**Memory Usage Test (260 Minutes):**

[image]

Comment: As I already told you, learning pointless things is pointless. Check out my edited answer for a much simpler implementation and a rextester usage demo.

Comment: Explain why it is pointless? 1. It fully works. 2. I learned something.

Comment: It fully works? Have you tested it in a multi threaded application? Did you check for memory leaks? Have you thought what will happen if someone doesn't clear the interval as ypu intended? Not to mention that your code is way too long and complicated then what you can get almost out of the box. There are better ways tp learn.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, Everyone has there own methods to learn. There are no memory leaks as far as I know, but I will check it.. it is not needed to clear the interval, I never intended it, it is optional, and works just like the `setInterval` and `clearInterval` in JavaScript, just like I planned it. And it is supposed to run on windows forms applications. But I will accept your solution because it is indeed shorter and I learned something from it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Black This does NOT do exactly what the javascript version does... also it does have a memory leak (You attach an event handler to the Tick event but never remove it...)

Comment: @Milney, What is different on the javascript methods? I will fix it, thanks for the hint. Why are you downvoting me?

Comment: @Black Well for a start, javascript is always single threaded so you do not have to worry about concurrency issues. For example, play around with having your timer tick start another timer, or have a different thread mess with your timer while in operation. For that matter changing the interval while the timer is running, even from the same thread, will not match javascripts behavior. But the question is really WHY are you trying to recreate the javascript function in C#, the languages have different characteristics so it doesn't make sense to do that - as others have said, use the .Net ones!

Comment: @Black - Yes but what would be more useful is learning the correct way to do it (by taking the advice other people have mentioned like reading the .Net implementation). There is no point in learning the wrong way to do something. Also - if you do not want advice on why this is a bad way to do it, why did you even post it to StackOverflow in the first place!

Comment: @Milney, **have a different thread mess with your timer while in operation**

I just tried to clear my timer in another event by using my clearInterval function, but it does not stop. I think this is what you meaned. Is there any logical explanation why this does not work or should I open a new question for this?

Comment: Ok nevermind, it was because I was using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, now I am using the `System.Timers.Timer` and it works :)